# Extend function "this" object

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an object of other functions:

```js
const fn = <T extends Record<string, (...args: any) => Promise<unknown>>>(
  t: T
) => {
  // code for binding `this` context for `t` variable methods.
};
```

I would like to extend `this` context of methods passed to `fn` with a few properties having the ability to access other methods from `this` at the same time (`foo` and `bar` in the example):

```js
fn({
  async foo() {},
  async bar() {
    this.foo // should reference foo function
    this.propertyA // should point to custom bound property
  },
});
```

I've tried something like that, but `T` seems to be `unknown` when used inside of its own definition, so original context is lost and I have only `{ propertyA: string }` as `this` type:

```js
const fn = <
  T extends Record<
    string,
    (this: T & { propertyA: string }, ...args: any) => Promise<unknown>
  >
>(
  t: T
) => {};

fn({
  async foo() {},
  async bar() {
    this.foo // not available
    this.propertyA // available
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the sort of inference you're looking for, you need to use the [special "magical"/intrinsic `ThisType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype):

```
const fn = <T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any) => Promise<unknown>>>(
    t: T & ThisType<T & { propertyA: string }>
) => { };

fn({
    async foo(x: number) { },
    async bar() {
        this.foo(3) // this works
        this.propertyA.toUpperCase(); // this too
    },
});
```

Your version, with a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters), ends up *requiring* that the methods have such a `this` context, but does not *infer* it.  Whereas `ThisType<T>` produces a contextual type for methods in which `this` is inferred how you want.  And note that `ThisType<T>` is "magical"; it is granted this inference behavior by the compiler itself and can't be re-implemented by user code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeAKjApgDylsAEwhgCUtQAnQ1AaywE8Q4Z0AaGACgDpeBDSgHMIALhh8wDAJTIAfDAAKlEAFsAlhCyoArmFpgQAdzCzTnALAAoGDZhQxmAGSsAFhvQMADlqcwA3jCeyt6UUAwAgmLQlGpggjAAvrJWMkjyAQkA3FZWCJx+VrbiEAxgwPAgIJw4YmDaKgBGWJQyGWyFtnwlZTANApytHUU2UG4Q3HCVnADMMgD0c3ZjMIYglLQQQ8OjGtxBICFh4dxQIACqniEAwl1YA5kwC0sadpVbCe2WCVKZQA)