# Extend "this" of an object

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns an object. Later on, this object will be extended with properties (e.g. `$watch`):

```
export default () => {
  const myObject = {
    property1: 'string1',
    property2: 1,
    init() {
      console.log('property1', this.property1)

      this.$watch('property1', (value) => { 
        console.log('property1 changed', value)
      })
    },
  }

  return myObject
}
```

```
interface OtherProps<T> {
  $watch: <K extends keyof T | string, V extends K extends keyof T ? T[K] : any>(
        property: K,
        callback: (newValue: V, oldValue: V) => void,
    ) => void;
  // ... other props
}
```

Is there a way to inject the properties of `OtherProps` to `myObject` so TypeScript doesn't say `Property '$watch' does not exist on type ...`?

I managed to type it this way but it's a bit too verbose for my taste as I have to type the definition separately:

```
type WithProps<T> = ThisType<T & OtherProps<T>>

type Test = WithProps<{
  property1: string
  property2: number
  init(): void
}>

export default () => {
  const myObject: Test = {
    property1: 'string1',
    property2: 1,
    init() {},
  }

  return myObject
}
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73748640) that seems to work well but I'm having a hard time adapting it to my case.

Comment: Does this question depend on "alpine.js" to make sense? If so, then you might want to tag it as such so that the relevant experts can see it.  Otherwise, if this is really just a TypeScript question, could you please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't depend on external libraries?

Comment: You need a noop wrapper, see https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00006-hard-simple-vue/README.md

Comment: I just mentioned Alpine because my current working solution is using the type AlpineComponent but this question is library agnostic as it's essentially about extending the type of an object. I will edit the question.

Comment: The verbosity can only be reduced by using a helper function (there is no way to infer a generic type's type argument directly; you need to do it with a generic function).  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4QoKw) work for you?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes! That's exactly it. Though in my context, it would make more sens that the function `withProps` returns the function I will export. I forgot to mention: this function can receive arguments. I [edited your example](https://shorturl.at/qCLZ1) with this in mind but I couldn't manage to type this properly.

Comment: Looks like you resolved the first problem and are now facing a followup problem.  Instead of expanding the scope here, I'd like to answer the original question as asked.  If you can't resolve the followup question after searching you could make another post for it.  (but, briefly, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxq1bW) might be the approach you should take... don't want to digress further about it here though)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for sharing this new example. I understood what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Typescript to infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument to `WithProps`, you'll need to write a generic helper function.  Type argument inference only happens when you call generic *functions*; there is no analogous behavior for generic *types*.  Here's one way to do it:

```
const withProps = <T,>(wp: T & ThisType<T & OtherProps<T>>) => wp;
```

This way, instead of writing `const myObj: WithProps<{⋯}> = {⋯}`, you can write `const myObj = withProps({⋯})` and the type of `myObj` will automatically be inferred the way you want.  I don't know that you actually need the type `WithProps`, so I just inlined it above.  Oh, and you really want `T & ThisType<T & OtherProps<T>>` instead of just `ThisType<T & OtherProps<T>>`.  Without `T &` you'd get the contextual `this` behavior provided by [the magical/intrinsic `ThisType` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype), but the resulting type of the object would have nothing to do with `T`.

Okay, let's try it:

```
const x = () => withProps({
  property1: 'string1',
  property2: 1,
  init() {
    console.log('property1', this.property1)
    this.$watch('property1', (value) => {
      console.log('property1 changed', value)
    })
  },
});
```

Looks good.  The `this` type inside `init()` knows about the properties and also `$watch`.  And the inferred type of `x` is

```
/* const x: () => {
    property1: string;
    property2: number;
    init(): void;
} & ThisType<{
    property1: string;
    property2: number;
    init(): void;
} & OtherProps<{
    property1: string;
    property2: number;
    init(): void;
}>> */
```

which behaves as specified:

```
console.log(x().property1.toUpperCase()) // "STRING1"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJgBbQApQPYAOAzgDwAqAfMgN4BQyyAJAO5xgIYBcyJA0shAAekEABMiyANYQAnnhjIyyAD7IiYKKADmAGmQA1AcIhiJ-ISPFTZ8xcgD8igNq8Ausm5wQMigAp6DMgE+ATQYDLcvDoBDAhwADbxAEaIkty+IBDM+gkArhDc+np48aI58fmFAJTIALxUAG54wKLRDDX1yE0tANwBAPT9yAB0o8h4mNBBIUS0AL60tAh4IOrIzMCYuIQStTxkOn7MBNxKAGSKGMBEZDKh5MgX6FhQ28TkFBQdVMd9SytrQR1ZC+b7rTYYN5EXx0BjBQhhGQARm4AHJ1JoQFokai2tMEVBwgAmbhIvGgTagmgxZDLVYlCDDeJ4LS+VHw0KE5G45CYa7DDmIpFVGl8ojDFhsDhswVcnF6XwNPIQMGwwKxAEMpksmUhIW0jBeLQQUQ8pUVFU0uYihhzaLWv79ABUtIBYGQgnSqppsvCKLUGm0fXVvpkJOQIFyAFsktBg4EKWBQdxuqI+nNHpdrrd7mq4Xq5dwMUGfQXidxIzG4zTE8mus00-NM88cDMSHn8Zy-UXA1j4-mCeWI9HY1B+8ha1UUw3059kE7+os6UQtczWYJQQKy8jhmA8ABVAicgDCcCIEFBNUGyAARABlMgAJQAkgA5ADiSJvQA)

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is to use the function this type to tell TypeScript what `this` will refer to:

`function myFn<T extends { ... }>(this: T){}`

Doing this means you can tell TypesScript that `this` must have some existing property.

Here is the `init` function declaration that I came up with:

```js
type $WatchType =  (property: string, callback: (value: unknown) => void) => void;

function init<
  T extends { property1: string; property2: number; $watch: $WatchType },
>(this: T) {
  console.log("property1", this.property1);

  this.$watch("property1", (value) => {
    console.log("property1 changed", value);
  });
}
```

Then, whatever function actually adds `$watch` should return the new object with `this` modified:

```js
type $WatchType = (
  property: string,
  callback: (value: unknown) => void,
) => void;

const myObject = {
  property1: "string1",
  property2: 1,
  init<T extends { property1: string; property2: number; $watch: $WatchType }>(
    this: T,
  ) {
    console.log("property1", this.property1);

    this.$watch("property1", (value) => {
      console.log("property1 changed", value);
    });
  },
};

function addWatch<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  input: T,
): T & { $watch: $WatchType } {
  return Object.assign(input, {
    $watch: (property: string, callback: (value: unknown) => void) => {},
  });
}

const doesntWork = myObject.init(); // errors because myObject doesn't have correct this
const doesWork = addWatch(myObject).init(); // works because myObject has correct this.
```

There might be some other magical way to do this that I'm not aware of, but this is how I'd do it.